# How to check if a specific number is present in the lines of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file named `in.txt`.

`in.txt`

```
0000fb435  00000326fab123bc2a 20
00003b4c6  0020346afeff655423 26
0000cb341  be3652a156fffcabd5 26
.
.
```

i need to check if number **20** is present in file and if present i need the output to look like this.

**Expected output**:

`out.txt`

```
0020fb435  00000326fab123bc2a 20 twenty_number
00003b4c6  0020346afeff655423 26 none
0000cb341  be3652a120fffcabd5 26 none
.
.
```

this is my current attempt:

```
with open("in.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
           line = line.strip()
           if '20' in line:
               fout.write(line + f" twenty_number \n")
```

this is **current output**:
`out.txt`

```
0020fb435  00000326fab123bc2a 20 twenty_number
00003b4c6  0020346afeff655423 26 twenty_number
0000cb341  be3652a120fffcabd5 26 twenty_number
.
.
```

this is because it is checking "20" in every line but i only need to check the last column.

Comment: You need to split the line first, and add a else-statement to append "none".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `endswith` as the `if` condition.

```
with open("in.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
           line = line.strip()
           if line.endswith('20'):
               fout.write(line + f" twenty_number \n")
           else:
               fout.write(line + f" none \n")
```

output in `out.txt`

```
0000fb435  00000326fab123bc2a 20 twenty_number 
00003b4c6  0020346afeff655423 26 none 
0000cb341  be3652a156fffcabd5 26 none
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("in.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            last_col = line.split()[-1]
            fout.write(f"{line.strip()} {'twenty_number' if '20' in last_col else 'none'}" )
```

output:

```
0020fb435  00000326fab123bc2a 20 twenty_number
00003b4c6  0020346afeff655423 26 none
0000cb341  be3652a120fffcabd5 26 none
```

Comment: This rather unattractively joins back stuff you just split apart, with different spacing. Probably split to a different variable and then just append the new text to the original line.